# Icons not showing using .html()

Tags: jquery, svg, icons

I'm working on simple form which display error messages, my problem is when I tried to add a icon on the alert messages, the icons is not showing. I'm using [feathericons](https://feathericons.com/) to generate the icons.

I made a simple snippet, the icons is showing normally but when I display it using jquery it doesn't work.

Hope you help me.

thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   feather.replace();
   
   $('button').click(function(){
      $('.alert').html('<i data-feather="activity"></i>');
   });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons@4.10.0/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>show Icon</button>
<div class="alert"></div>
<hr>
<i data-feather="home"></i>
<i data-feather="alert-circle"></i>
<i data-feather="globe"></i>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try This.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons@4.10.0/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>show Icon</button>
<div class="alert"></div>
<hr>
<i data-feather="home"></i>
<i data-feather="alert-circle"></i>
<i data-feather="globe"></i>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   feather.replace();

   $('button').click(function(){
      $('.alert').html('<i data-feather="activity"></i>');
      feather.replace();
   });

});
</script>
```